# Add www. prefix to existing A record in AWS hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have transfered my domain name from godaddy to AWS route 53.

I have set up a hosted zone (and transferred the nameservers) with the domain name:

`wp360.com`

I have added an A record for:

`wp360.com`

The website is now live but can only be found when using the url `wp360.com`

How do I make it visible with the prefix www? ie. `www.wp360.com` as this doesnt work at the moment.

Can I create an additional A record in the same hosted zone? or will that overwrite the existing A record? or do I need to create a new hosted zone or alias? Very confused...

Comment: It is only CNAME issue. Just add CNAME on your control panel and it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new CNAME record set inside your existing hosted zone.

Your CNAME record name will be `www.wp360.com` | TTL `60` | Alias: `no` | Value: `wp360.com`